# c#: better threading architecture

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

I am interested to get some ideas from you about what would be a good/better threading architecture that respects the rules described below:

- A thread must be running for the life of the application, in the sleep/wait mode if there is no work in the queue to be performed.
- A thread must be of a BelowNormal priority (this eliminates possibility of using ThreadPool).
- The thread must give its feedback to the main thread upon completion of task.
- Thread will monitor a Queue<T> to get more jobs to be performed.

I am using .Net Framework 4.0

Let me know what you think :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I need to implement my own multi-threaded processing, I usually use something like this:

```
public class MyWorker<T> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Queue<T> _taskQueue; // task queue
    private readonly object _threadLock = new object();
    private Thread _thread; // worker thread
    private ManualResetEvent _evExit;
    private AutoResetEvent _evNewData;

    /// <summary>Override this to process data.</summary>
    protected abstract void ProcessData(T data);

    /// <summary>Override this to set other thread priority.</summary>
    protected virtual ThreadPriority ThreadPriority
    {
        get { return ThreadPriority.BelowNormal; }
    }

    protected MyWorker()
    {
        _taskQueue = new Queue<T>();
        _evExit = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        _evNewData = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    }

    ~MyWorker()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    private void ThreadProc()
    {
        try
        {
            var wh = new WaitHandle[] { _evExit, _evNewData };
            while(true)
            {
                T data = default(T);
                bool gotData = false;
                lock(_taskQueue) // sync
                {
                    if(_taskQueue.Count != 0) // have data?
                    {
                        data = _taskQueue.Dequeue();
                        gotData = true;
                    }
                }
                if(!gotData)
                {
                    if(WaitHandle.WaitAny(wh) == 0) return; // demanded stop
                    continue; //we have data now, grab it
                }
                ProcessData(data);
                if(_evExit.WaitOne(0)) return;
            }
        }
        catch(ThreadInterruptedException)
        {
            // log warning - this is not normal
        }
        catch(ThreadAbortException)
        {
            // log warning - this is not normal
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        lock(_threadLock)
        {
            if(_thread != null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Already running.");
            _thread = new Thread(ThreadProc)
            {
                Name = "Worker Thread",
                IsBackground = true,
                Priority = ThreadPriority,
            };
            _thread.Start();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        lock(_threadLock)
        {
            if(_thread == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Is not running.");
            _evExit.Set();
            if(!_thread.Join(1000))
                _thread.Abort();
            _thread = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Enqueue data for processing.</summary>
    public void EnqueueData(T data)
    {
        lock(_taskQueue)
        {
            _taskQueue.Enqueue(data);
            _evNewData.Set(); // wake thread if it is sleeping
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Clear all pending data processing requests.</summary>
    public void ClearData()
    {
        lock(_taskQueue)
        {
            _taskQueue.Clear();
            _evNewData.Reset();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        lock(_threadLock)
        {
            if(_thread != null)
            {
                _evExit.Set();
                if(!_thread.Join(1000))
                    _thread.Abort();
                _thread = null;
            }
        }
        _evExit.Close();
        _evNewData.Close();
        if(disposing)
            _taskQueue.Clear();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> - A thread must be of a BelowNormal priority (this eliminates possibility of using ThreadPool).

This seems to be the main stumbling block for using the TPL and ThreadPool. Are you sure you're not over-estimating the usefulness of a lower priority?

You will have to put in a lot of work to come up with something that will always be much less powerful (and much less tested/reliable) than the TPL.

I would reconsider this.

Answer (score 1):

By reading above conditions

Some questions

1- Is there any other thread which will populate jobs in Queue< T > ?

if the answer is yes than Producer / Consumer Deign Pattern can be used here i am not aware of .net 4.0 but this design can be implemented in .net 3.5.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f%28VS.80%29.aspx) for example.

Comment: It is important to note the article linked to here regarding the producer/consumer pattern is incorrect. It contains a very subtle, but nasty bug that can cause it to get live-locked. Microsoft really needs to banish this article.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I roll my own usually, because I like having much tighter control.

I use this in Media Browser:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using MediaBrowser.Library.Logging;

namespace MediaBrowser.Library.Threading {

    public static class Async {

        public const string STARTUP_QUEUE = "Startup Queue";

        class ThreadPool {
            List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
            List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
            string name;
            volatile int maxThreads = 1;

            public ThreadPool(string name) {
                Debug.Assert(name != null);
                if (name == null) {
                    throw new ArgumentException("name should not be null");
                }
                this.name = name;
            }


            public void SetMaxThreads(int maxThreads) {
                Debug.Assert(maxThreads > 0);
                if (maxThreads < 1) {
                    throw new ArgumentException("maxThreads should be larger than 0");
                }

                this.maxThreads = maxThreads;
            }

            public void Queue(Action action, bool urgent) {
                Queue(action, urgent, 0);
            }

            public void Queue(Action action, bool urgent, int delay) {

                if (delay > 0) {
                    Timer t = null;
                    t = new Timer(_ =>
                    {
                        Queue(action, urgent, 0);
                        t.Dispose();
                    }, null, delay, Timeout.Infinite);
                    return;
                }

                lock (threads) {
                    // we are spinning up too many threads
                    // should be fixed 
                    if (maxThreads > threads.Count) {
                        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
                        t.IsBackground = true;
                        // dont affect the UI.
                        t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
                        t.Name = "Worker thread for " + name;
                        t.Start();
                        threads.Add(t);
                    }
                }

                lock (actions) {
                    if (urgent) {
                        actions.Insert(0, action);
                    } else {
                        actions.Add(action);
                    }

                    Monitor.Pulse(actions);
                }
            }

            private void ThreadProc() {

                while (true) {

                    lock (threads) {
                        if (maxThreads < threads.Count) {
                            threads.Remove(Thread.CurrentThread);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    List<Action> copy;

                    lock (actions) {
                        while (actions.Count == 0) {
                            Monitor.Wait(actions);
                        }
                        copy = new List<Action>(actions);
                        actions.Clear();
                    }

                    foreach (var action in copy) {
                        action();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        static Dictionary<string, ThreadPool> threadPool = new Dictionary<string, ThreadPool>();

        public static Timer Every(int milliseconds, Action action) {
            Timer timer = new Timer(_ => action(), null, 0, milliseconds);
            return timer;
        }

        public static void SetMaxThreads(string uniqueId, int threads) {
            GetThreadPool(uniqueId).SetMaxThreads(threads);
        }

        public static void Queue(string uniqueId, Action action) {
            Queue(uniqueId, action, null);
        }

        public static void Queue(string uniqueId, Action action, int delay) {
            Queue(uniqueId, action, null,false, delay);
        }

        public static void Queue(string uniqueId, Action action, Action done) {
            Queue(uniqueId, action, done, false);
        }

        public static void Queue(string uniqueId, Action action, Action done, bool urgent) {
            Queue(uniqueId, action, done, urgent, 0);
        }

        public static void Queue(string uniqueId, Action action, Action done, bool urgent, int delay) {

            Debug.Assert(uniqueId != null);
            Debug.Assert(action != null);

            Action workItem = () =>
            {
                try {
                    action();
                } catch (ThreadAbortException) { /* dont report on this, its normal */ } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Debug.Assert(false, "Async thread crashed! This must be fixed. " + ex.ToString());
                    Logger.ReportException("Async thread crashed! This must be fixed. ", ex);
                }
                if (done != null) done();
            };

            GetThreadPool(uniqueId).Queue(workItem, urgent, delay);
        }

        private static ThreadPool GetThreadPool(string uniqueId) {
            ThreadPool currentPool;
            lock (threadPool) {
                if (!threadPool.TryGetValue(uniqueId, out currentPool)) {
                    currentPool = new ThreadPool(uniqueId);
                    threadPool[uniqueId] = currentPool;
                }
            }
            return currentPool;
        }
    }

}
```

It has a fairly elegant API, only feature I would like to add one day is scavenging empty thread pools.

Usage:

```
 // Set the threads for custom thread pool 
 Async.SetMaxThreads("Queue Name", 10); 
 // Perform an action on the custom threadpool named: "Queue Name", when done call ImDone  
 Async.Queue("Queue Name", () => DoSomeThing(foo), () => ImDone(foo));
```

This has a few handy oveloads that allow you to queue delayed actions, and another to push in urgent jobs that skip to the front of the queue.

Answer (score 1):

This situation screams [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28VS.100%29.aspx?ppud=4) loud and clear. Create a dedicated thread that watches the queue with its priority set approriately. The `BlockingCollection.Take` method will block automatically when there are no items in the queue.

```
public class Example
{
  private BlockingCollection<WorkItem> m_Queue = new BlockingCollection<WorkItem>();

  public event EventHandler<WorkItemEventArgs> WorkItemCompleted;

  public Example()
  {
    var thread = new Thread(
      () =>
      {
        while (true)
        {
          WorkItem item = m_Queue.Take();
          // Add code to process the work item here.
          if (WorkItemCompleted != null)
          {
             WorkItemCompleted(this, new WorkItemEventArgs(item));
          }
        }
      });
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
    thread.Start();
  }

  public void Add(WorkItem item)
  {
    m_Queue.Add(item);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A thread pool sounds like just the thing.  Actually, you can change the priority of .NET's own thread pool by setting the process priority.  Bump the process priority down a notch and your UI up a notch and you should have a UI at normal priority and thread pool at lower priority.

Comment: I wouldn't recomment changing the process priority. Also if you use BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS for the process, you'd have to use THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST for the GUI thread to get the same priority that a NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS/THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL thread has. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685100(VS.85).aspx